# canvas getting not clear completely on canvas.clear()

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am using canvas for creating shapes like (circle,square,etc) and I need to clear the canvas, I have tried with `canvas.clear()` it shows empty array when checked with `canvas.getObjects()` but still shapes are visible and sometimes extra shapes as well.

[circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93Vpi.png)

[canvas objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TI9c.png)

[clear canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvxrO.png)

[shape still visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLoHd.png)

[extra boundary as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5GmW.png)

I have also checked if there is any reference issue, but no only one canvas object.

can anyone give direction what can be the reason, or I have missed something.

Thanks

Comment: if there is no object it wont render anything.  here is demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/durga598/t1pryuua/1/) clearing 1000 particles. can you make a minimal snippet stating your issue?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Actually it is some sort of undo and redo activity and this extra shapes are coming when `{"objects":[],"background":{}}` is passed to `canvas.loadFromJSON`

Comment: still if there is no objects in objects array, then it wont draw anything. Check your code again.

Comment: Plz check the images as well, It shows empty array but still shape is visble

Comment: Could you add your code / create a fiddle? It may shed light on what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

After more and more debugging, it comes out to be some overlay issue.
Actually when shape is added to canvas, two more things are done

1. setting overlay for shape
2. clipping the region

so somehow on loading JSON, extra layers were appearing on the screen. SO fixed the overlay for shape and clipping again when JSON got loaded, and it worked.

PS: There might be some reference issue as well, because when I do `canvas.clear()` then `canvas.getObjects().length` shows 0, but still shapes visible to canvas.

Thanks